# LED brightness variations

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide, led, resistor

I'm using two different types of code and noticing that in the first set up the last LED is dimmer than the rest. Then in the second set up, the first LED is brighter than the rest. I would like to know what is causing it and how I may fix it. My ultimate goal is to wire 30 LEDs on an Arduino Mega and time them to a sequence. I'm building the project from the ground up starting with 3 LEDs on an Arduino Uno. I really appreciate your insights.

The first set up is using a pushbutton as a switch to turn on 3 LEDs in a timed series, using 220ohm resistors. The first two LEDs wired to pins 2 and 4 are visibly bright while the last you can barely see a little dot of light.

[image: pushbutton controlled 3 LEDs on Arduino Uno]

Here's the code for it:

```
int ledState = 0;
int ledPin1 = 2;
int ledPin2 = 4;
int ledPin3 = 7;
int buttonState = 0;
const int buttonPin = 12;
int buttonNew;
int buttonOld;
int fiveInterval = 3000;
int oneInterval = 1000;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(ledPin1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledPin2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);

}

void loop() {
  buttonNew = digitalRead(buttonPin);

  if(buttonOld == 0 && buttonNew == 1){
    if(ledState == 0){
      digitalWrite(ledPin1, HIGH);
      delay(fiveInterval);
      digitalWrite(ledPin2, HIGH);
      delay(fiveInterval);
      digitalWrite(ledPin3, HIGH);
      ledState = 1;
//      for(int i ){
//        
//      }
    }else{
      digitalWrite(ledPin1, LOW);
      digitalWrite(ledPin2, LOW);
      ledState = 0;
    }
  }
  buttonOld = buttonNew;
  delay(100);
}
```

The second set up is some code I borrowed from a tutorial. The 1st LED (wired to pin 2) is several times brighter than following LEDs. This one is a timed on/off of 3 LEDs, using 220ohm resistors.
[image: 3 LEDs lighting up in a series on an Arduino Uno]
Here's the code for it:

```
#define LED_PIN_1 2
#define LED_PIN_2 4
#define LED_PIN_3 7
#define LED_NUMBER 3
byte LEDPinArray[LED_NUMBER] = { LED_PIN_1,
                                 LED_PIN_2,
                                 LED_PIN_3 };
int LEDIndex = 0;
void initAllLEDs()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < LED_NUMBER; i++) {
    pinMode(LEDPinArray[i], OUTPUT);
  }
}
void powerOnSelectedLEDOnly(int index)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < LED_NUMBER; i++) {
    if (i == index) {
      digitalWrite(LEDPinArray[i], HIGH);
    }
    else {
      digitalWrite(LEDPinArray[i], LOW);
    }
  }
}
void toggleNextLED()
{
  LEDIndex++;
  if (LEDIndex >= LED_NUMBER) {
    LEDIndex = 0;
  }
  powerOnSelectedLEDOnly(LEDIndex);
}
void setup()
{
  initAllLEDs();
  digitalWrite(LEDPinArray[LEDIndex], HIGH);
}
void loop() 
{
  delay(1000);
  toggleNextLED();
}
```

Comment: rightmost LED does not have a resistor in series

Comment: the code would be simpler if you use arrays ... `ledPin[1]`, `ledPin[2]`, etc ... that way you can use a loop to turn on all that have an index that is less than or equal to `LEDIndex`

Comment: You're not setting all the LEDs to be OUTPUT, so one is being powered through the internal pullup resistor.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your helpful suggestions. I've corrected the errors and also spent some time on writing the code with arrays, and now I'm able to time my 30 LEDs with equal brightness in a sequence. Now on to the next challenge...controlling these with two pushbuttons! :)